# search via 'order' in where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

**Query** :

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as order 
FROM VendorTransaction 
WHERE order_id = 7496 
AND payment_mode = 'order'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

> **Error**: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order 
>   FROM VendorTransaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order is a reserved  word  change with another one

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as my_order 
FROM VendorTransaction 
WHERE order_id = 7496 
AND payment_mode = 'order'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

or use backtics

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as `order`
FROM VendorTransaction 
WHERE order_id = 7496 
AND payment_mode = 'order'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

***use it:***
SELECT SUM(amount) as 'order' FROM VendorTransaction WHERE order_id = 7496 AND payment_mode = 'order' ORDER BY id DESC